*Update* Excel VBA: Looping an Auto-Fill PDF, Checkbox Issue
I have a Loop template built to export information from excel to Auto-Fill a PDF Form.  I am very new to writing in VBA and can't figure out how to have the macro Check a Box (sendkeys 'enter') if there is data present or skip over (sendkeys 'tab') to the next section of the form.  I am trying to use If, Then logic but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about it
I originally had the value as "Yes" or " " but thought having a numerical value of "1" or " " would help to bypass some of the original errors I was receiving
When I run the macro now I receive a Runtime Error '13' Information Mismatch message but I don't understand how to correct this in what I have written
Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!
Application.SendKeys Format(.Range("P" & CustRow).Value), True 'Quit Box
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
If .Range("Q2:Q9999").Value = "1" Then
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}"
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Else
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
End If
    
Application.SendKeys Format(.Range("Q" & CustRow).Value), True 'Quit Reason
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Adding more code for clarity
Sub CreatePDFForms()
Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFolder, LastName As String
Dim ApptDate As Date
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long
With Sheet1
If .Range("A2").Value = Empty Or .Range("A4").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Both PDF Template and Saved PDF Locations are required for macro to run"
    Exit Sub
End If

For CustRow = 7 To 10 'LastRow

LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Row
PDFTemplateFile = .Range("A2").Value 'Template File Name
SavePDFFolder = .Range("A4").Value 'Save PDF Folder
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFTemplateFile
Application.Wait Now + 0.00006

LastName = .Range("E" & CustRow).Value 'Employee Name
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys LastName, True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys .Range("F" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee SSN
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("G" & CustRow).Value, True 'Employee Address
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

If Dir(SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & ".pdf") <> Empty Then Kill (SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & ".pdf")
Application.SendKeys "%(n)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys SavePDFFolder & "\" & LastName & ".pdf"
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys "%(s)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002

Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys "(Tab)", True
Application.SendKeys "(Enter)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00002

Next CustRow

Application.SendKeys "{numlock}%s", True

End With
End Sub


.Range("Q2:Q9999").Value is a 2-dimensional array, not a single value.  Maybe add some more code so we can see the looping part...

@TimWilliams ok i will add it as an update to the main post

Why check the whole range Q2:Q9999? Is the value you want to check actually on the same row as CustRow ? Your initial code doesn't appear in your expanded view, so it's difficult to see how they're related.
